# Finding the first row index value where a condition occurs

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Suppose I have a data frame called `county_compare_df`. It looks like this:

[image]

I want to find the index value (`CO_FIPS`) of the first row where column `Pop_Diff` > 0.

```
first_value = county_compare_df.loc[county_compare_df['Pop_Diff'] > 0].iloc[0]
```

The above throws an `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`. How can I fix this to achieve my desired outcome (EX: '01011')?

**UpDate**
Per the comment below, I tried this:

```
tt = county_compare_df.loc[county_compare_df['Pop_Diff'] == 0.0].iloc[0]
print(tt)
```

which returns:

```
Pop_SFHA_x     3.420000e+03
HU_SFHA_x      1.596140e+03
Area_SFHA_x    9.082000e+01
HUC8           1.512091e+08
Pop_SFHA_y     3.420000e+03
HU_SFHA_y      1.596140e+03
Area_SFHA_y    9.082000e+01
Pop_Diff       0.000000e+00
HU_Diff        0.000000e+00
Area_Diff      0.000000e+00
Name: 01001, dtype: float64
```

All I want is the Name, `01001`. How do I get that value?

Comment: You probably have no rows where `Pop_Diff` is greater than 0.

Comment: first_value = county_compare_df[county_compare_df['Pop_Diff']>0].index[0]

Comment: That also throws `IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`. I thing @ifly6 is right; maybe there are no rows where the condition is met.

Comment: Then just try print(tt.name) I think you got it man

Comment: Also, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) on how to post a proper question. Your question needs to have samples data, output data, and desired output data so that they can be copied and worked on here. Samples in yourquestion  have to be simple and reproducible.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) article on posting a GOOD QUESTION. You don't have sample data to work with, and an example of what you want the output to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# will get you the index number of the first item
tt = county_compare_df.loc[county_compare_df['Pop_Diff'] == 0.0].index[0] 

print(tt)
```